# Unable to expose more than one Service - Spring WebServiceExporter

Tags: asp.net, web-services, spring.net

Hi I am still fairly new to Spring in general. I have been using WebServiceExporter to expose my WebServices. However, when I tried to add another WebService to my Web.xml I get the following error:

```
[ArgumentException: Duplicate type name within an assembly.]
System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, Type enclosingType) +14200621
System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderData.CheckTypeNameConflict(String strTypeName, TypeBuilder enclosingType) +91
System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.Init(String fullname, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces, ModuleBuilder module, PackingSize iPackingSize, Int32 iTypeSize, TypeBuilder enclosingType) +161
System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefineTypeNoLock(String name, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent, Type[] interfaces, PackingSize packingSize, Int32 typesize) +103
System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder.DefineType(String name, TypeAttributes attr, Type parent) +289
Spring.Proxy.DynamicProxyManager.CreateTypeBuilder(String typeName, Type baseType) +145

[ArgumentException: Proxy already registered for "UserWebService" as Type "UserWebService".]
Spring.Proxy.DynamicProxyManager.CreateTypeBuilder(String typeName, Type baseType) +353
Spring.Proxy.CompositionProxyTypeBuilder.BuildProxyType() +149
Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceExporter.GenerateProxy() +333
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InvokeInitMethods(Object target, String name, IConfigurableObjectDefinition definition) +269
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.ConfigureObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper) +660
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectFactory.ConfigureObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper) +135
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure) +933

[ObjectCreationException: Error creating object with name 'UserWebService' defined in 'file [C:\CODE\Kupla\Kupla\Web.xml] line 13' : Initialization of object failed : Proxy already registered for "UserWebService" as Type "UserWebService".]
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure) +1419
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.CreateAndCacheSingletonInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments) +389
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(String name, Type requiredType, Object[] arguments, Boolean suppressConfigure) +2103
Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.PreInstantiateSingletons() +875
Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.Refresh() +1225
Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext..ctor(WebApplicationContextArgs args) +179
_dynamic_Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext..ctor(Object[] ) +252
Spring.Context.Support.RootContextInstantiator.InvokeContextConstructor(ConstructorInfo ctor) +168
Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.InstantiateContext(IApplicationContext parentContext, Object configContext, String contextName, Type contextType, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] resources) +192
Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler.InstantiateContext(IApplicationContext parent, Object configContext, String contextName, Type contextType, Boolean caseSensitive, String[] resources) +413
Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler.Create(Object parent, Object configContext, XmlNode section) +520

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating context 'spring.root': Duplicate type name within an assembly.]
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult) +347
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) +2277
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject) +1849
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey) +69
Spring.Util.ConfigurationUtils.GetSection(String sectionName) +270
Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext.GetContextInternal(String virtualPath) +1663
Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +665
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +192
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +1678
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +390
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +194
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +293
```

Has anyone else experienced this with Spring before, I am really struggling to see what is wrong. My web.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

<object type="default.aspx">
<property name="SessionObjectHolder" ref="SessionObjectHolder"/>
</object>

<object type="home.aspx">
<property name="UserBLL" ref="UserBLL"/>
<property name="SessionObjectHolder" ref="SessionObjectHolder"/>
</object>

<object id="UserWebService" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceExporter, Spring.Web">
<property name="TargetName" value="UserWebServiceDTO"/>
<property name="Namespace" value="http://test.co.uk"/>
<property name="Description" value="This is User Web Service"/>
<property name="TypeAttributes">
  <list>
    <object type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptServiceAttribute, System.Web.Extensions"/>
  </list>
</property>
</object>

<object id="UserWebServiceDTO" type="Kupla.ServiceLayer.UserWebService, Kupla.ServiceLayer">
<property name="UserBLL" ref="UserBLL" />
</object>

<object id="SessionObjectHolderWebService" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceExporter, Spring.Web">
<property name="TargetName" value="SessionObjectHolderWebServiceDTO"/>
<property name="Namespace" value="http://test.co.uk"/>
<property name="Description" value="This is the session object holder web service"/>
<property name="TypeAttributes">
  <list>
    <object type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptServiceAttribute, System.Web.Extensions"/>
  </list>
</property>
</object>

<object id="SessionObjectHolderWebServiceDTO" type="Kupla.ServiceLayer.SessionObjectHolderWebService, Kupla.ServiceLayer">
<property name="UserBLL" ref="UserBLL" />
</object>
</objects>
```

Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do your `asmx` or `svc` files exist? They should be removed when creating services by Spring, because one instance is created by Spring and second by IIS/.NET.

**Edit**

I haven't found this earlier, but `WebServiceExporter` registers type of object's name - `UserWebService` and `SessionObjectHolderWebService` in your case. But these types already exists (created by yourself), you call those objects with `DTO` suffix. Try to add suffix `Exporter` to objects created by `WebServiceExporter`.

The reason why you get different error while swapping services in config file is because Spring only returns the very first error. It can be quite painful in large projects.

Comment: Hi Jan, I have the two classes in my Service Layer. SessionObjectHolderWebService.cs and UserWebService.cs. It is peculiar, because when I change the order in which the web services are declared in the web.xml. The error will tell me that SessionObjectHolderWebservice is being duplicated.